# Get page number with React Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have a react table created with react-table and I am trying to get the page number so I can pass it in as parameter in another function.  However I have absolutely no idea how to do this or if it is possible.  Does anyone know how I could get it?
Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, take the page number is probably the easy part in your problem. Take a look at [this](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/controlled-component) part of documentation, you gonna find some way to control (in your component state) the actual page of the table. Now the problem is send this page to other component. Maybe you need to use Redux...

Answer (score 0):

```
<ReactTable
        getTdProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {console.log(state['page'])}
        data={this.props.data}
        columns={[HERE YOUR DATA]}
        ETC/>
```